# Access parent property path in custom validator

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I'm writing a custom `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`. I'd like to include a custom property path on my `ConstraintViolation`, including the parent property path. So:

```
class BaseClass {
  @Valid MyProperty first;
}

@MyValidator class MyProperty {
  String someField;
}

class MyValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, MyProperty> { 
  // ...
  public boolean isValid(MyProperty value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
     context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
     context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("My message")
         // How to access the parent property name "first" here? 
         .addPropertyNode("my custom property") 
         .addConstraintViolation()
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is to add a `.addBeanNode()` call *after* the `.addPropertyNode()` call. This will actually add the parent node name *before* the property name. Note that you cannot call `addBeanNode()` before calling `addPropertyNode()` since the builder behind it doesn't allow that.